# undefined method `table_name' for Post:Module Did you mean? table_name_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm building an API with the [kollegorna's tutorial](https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/).
I used [ActiveHashRelation](https://github.com/kollegorna/active_hash_relation) for displays serialiazed arrays properly.

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb
class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  include ActiveHashRelation
  def index
    posts = apply_filters(Post::Post.all, params)

    render json: posts, each_serializer: Api::V1::PostSerializer
  end
end
```

The problem is that I have a model `Post::Post` and the module `Post`. It's like it can not found the correct model.

```
# app/models/post/post.rb
class Post::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :body
end

# app/models/post.rb
module Post
  def self.table_name_prefix
     'post_'
  end
end
```

I think it's because of ActiveHashrelation because when I write `posts = Post::Post.all` it's working. But I can't filter the array.

Comment: Having a model named `Post` and a module named `Post` is going to cause trouble. If you can give them slightly different names that would help avoid confusion between `Post::Post` and `::Post`. It's probable you're using `Post` somewhere you meant to use `Post::Post`.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you